# Can't make click handler working when I click an image

Tags: jquery, html, css

html:

```
<section class="one">
<div id="wrap">
    <img src="./images/moon.png" alt="moon" style="width:200px;height:200px" Class="moon">
</div>
</section>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }

 section {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

h1 { 
text-align: Center;
font: 15px impact, sans-serif;
color: white;
font-size: 350%
}
#wrap { 
width: 900px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
}
img.moon {
position: relative;
left: 900px;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.moon').css('opacity', 0.4);  
    $('.moon').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img').stop().fadeTo('slow',1);        
    });
});
```

The first line works. The image starts at 0.4 opacity. The next part is the issue. The code in it is does not work. If I change the second line to  `$('*').click(function() {`  (remove the class and put '*') and then click randomly on my website it works, the image fades in. If I put the image class in and click the image it does not work.

Comment: You should provide your HTML aswell. Secondly, you add `opacity: 0.4` to `.moon`, but then set it to `1` for `<img>` inside `.moon`. Are you sure you have done what you want?

Comment: $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow',1);  There's no need to find image since $(this) is already pointing to the image via moon class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/epb0bdq0/)**  Remove `.find()` from your code and all is done:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.moon').css('opacity', 0.4);  
    $('.moon').click(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow',1);        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You addi opacity to your div that is parent of the image. Even if the children of that div have opacity 1, they will appear with 0.4, because their parent has that opacity. 
When you set opacity of a selector, all children will receive that opacity recursively.

So, you also have to manipulate the opacity of the `.moon` selector.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.moon').css('opacity', 0.4);  
    $('.moon').click(function(){
        $(this).css('opacity', 1);
        $(this).find('img').stop().fadeTo('slow',1);        
    });
});
```

Comment: This almost worked, with this code clicking the image change the opacity to 1 with no fade. The answer that said remove ".find()" from one of the lines was dead on. His solution worked perfectly!

Comment: @Hugh because you set opacity to `$('.moon')` and then trying to change opacity of another elements, as I have already said in comments. So Sanki's answer is what I'm talking about.